# how to create VM from Azure CLi with exising key pair?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I tried to create VM from another VM via Azure CLI with this command :

```
 az vm create \
    --resource-group my_resource \
    --name newVMfromImage \
    --image firstMachine-image \
    --admin-username user_name \
    --data-disk-sizes-gb 150 20 --size Standard_B1ms \
      --verbose \
      ----ssh-key-value /path/to/publick/key/azure.pub
```

But I get this error :

> az: error: unrecognized arguments: ----ssh-key-value
>   /path/to/publick/key/azure.pub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, the 4 dashes (`----`) indicates a wrong transmission while uploading the `.PUB` file.

Remove the 2 additional dashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
----ssh-key-value /path/to/publick/key/azure.pub
```

should only be:

```
--ssh-key-value /path/to/publick/key/azure.pub
```

Remove the 2 additional dashes.